# Adding numpy arrays of different shape

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add two vectors, one of which is `(n,1)` and the other `(n,)` such that the type is `(n,)`

Just adding them with **+** gives the type `(n,1)`. 
What is the function to convert it to a vector (same type as `np.zeros(n)`)?
Or to compute the sum directly into this format?

Answer (score 1):

with `.squeeze` you can convert a (n,1) vector into an (n,) vector, then adding should work